# Drawing Bruhat--Tits trees with TikZ

Tags: tikz-pgf, trees

I am not a regular user of TikZ, and I was wondering if there was a quick way of drawing trees that look like

[image: this] ?

(the picture seems to have been taken from page 71 of J. P. Serre's book on trees).

Here is some motivation for my quiry: I am using some elementary rank-one Bruhat--Tits theory in a project that I'm currently writing up, and I feel it would be nicer with some pictures (the main reason I'm using trees rather than matrix computations is to make things more understandable).

Comment: You should be able to do this with TikZ and a Lindenmayer system. See Chapter 33 of the TikZ/`pgf` manual (version 2).

Comment: The second proper name brought me here...

Answer (score 26, accepted):

The `trees` library provides a `grow cyclic` key/growth function.

A few styles for the levels and a few `child foreach` path operators give you the following.

### Code

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{trees}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
  grow cyclic,
  level distance=1cm,
  level/.style={
    level distance/.expanded=\ifnum#1>1 \tikzleveldistance/1.5\else\tikzleveldistance\fi,
    nodes/.expanded={\ifodd#1 fill\else fill=none\fi}
  },
  level 1/.style={sibling angle=120},
  level 2/.style={sibling angle=90},
  level 3/.style={sibling angle=90},
  level 4/.style={sibling angle=45},
  nodes={circle,draw,inner sep=+0pt, minimum size=2pt},
  ]
\path[rotate=30]
  node {}
  child foreach \cntI in {1,...,3} {
    node {}
    child foreach \cntII in {1,...,2} { 
      node {}
      child foreach \cntIII in {1,...,2} {
        node {}
        child foreach \cntIV in {1,...,2} {
          node {}
          child foreach \cntV in {1,...,2} {}
        }
      }
    }
  };
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

### Output

[image]