# Permutation tree diagram

Tags: tikz-trees, trees

I need to draw a diagram that looks something like this. I found that the qtree package wouldn't let me create trees without labels for the nodes, and with tikz it seems possible but manually spacing the nodes appears to be a waste of time. It seems like this would be a relatively common graph to plot, so is there anything I can use to plot it?

[image: Factorial graph]

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436/184389) Please, provide a [MWE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/184389) showing what you have tried so far and what abstract notion you are struggling with. Indeed, as it is written, this question falls into the 'do-it-for-me' category of questions which is not well received on this website.

Comment: @KersouMan Thanks. Given that there is already an answer, I'll remember this for next time. (I don't have the code I used any more, since I gave up and just removed it from my latex file)

Comment: Is that all you need? For each level one child less than at the previous level? Reminds me of [Q135760](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/135760) just without the `grow cyclic`.

Answer (score 6):

This can be done with tikz by just defining some sibling distances manually and using for loops.

#### Code

```
\documentclass[margin=5mm]{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{trees}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
    level 1/.style={sibling distance=30mm},
    level 2/.style={sibling distance=10mm},
    level 3/.style={sibling distance=5mm},
    shape=circle,
    every node/.style={draw, fill, inner sep=0pt},
    level distance=10mm,
]

    \node {} child foreach \i in {1,...,4}
        { node {} child foreach \i in {1,...,3}
            { node {} child foreach \i in {1,...,2}
                { node {} child
                    { node {} }
                }
            }
        };
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

#### Result

[image]